# Baking results are blurry

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, baking, procedural

I used a subdivided plane and manually changed the positions of vertices but when i decided to bake the textures in order to import model with baked textures (for game engines) i found that the results aren't as the unbaked ones.I baked them at the resolution of 2k. I even applied the scale,rotation but it not worked. The original [image: not baked]

The baked

[image: baked]

This is the procedural shader

[image]

4K BAKED

[image]

Comment: Can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file?

Comment: Unfortunately After packing the textures into the .blend file the file size is greater than 30 mb

Comment: Are you displaying this in blender or is this in some game engine?

Comment: this is in blender 3.0

Comment: I just bake texture very simply, nothing complex but the issue is still, all of my bakes looks like that

Comment: Does it go away if you raise the resolution of the bake image?

Comment: I was just about to comment the same thing as Jakemoyo: what is the resolution of your baked texture?

Comment: its was baked at 2k resolution

Comment: I edited the post and added a 4k baked image.

Comment: it is near to the procedural material but still something is missing